# What pattern to utilize to use a Vec of differing nested generic types/trait objects?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a pattern where different *Processors* can dictate the input type they take and produce a unified output (currently a fixed type, but I'd like to get it generic once this current implementation is working).

Below is a minimal example:

```rust
use std::convert::From;

use processor::NoOpProcessor;

use self::{
    input::{Input, InputStore},
    output::UnifiedOutput,
    processor::{MultiplierProcessor, Processor, StringProcessor},
};

mod input {
    use std::collections::HashMap;

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct Input<T>(pub T);

    #[derive(Default)]
    pub struct InputStore(HashMap<String, String>);

    impl InputStore {
        pub fn insert<K, V>(mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Self
        where
            K: ToString,
            V: ToString,
        {
            let key = key.to_string();
            let value = value.to_string();
            self.0.insert(key, value);

            self
        }

        pub fn get<K, V>(&self, key: K) -> Option<Input<V>>
        where
            K: ToString,
            for<'a> &'a String: Into<V>,
        {
            let key = key.to_string();
            self.0.get(&key).map(|value| Input(value.into()))
        }
    }
}

mod processor {
    use super::{input::Input, output::UnifiedOutput};

    use super::I32Input;

    pub struct NoOpProcessor;

    pub trait Processor {
        type I;
        fn process(&self, input: &Input<Self::I>) -> UnifiedOutput;
    }

    impl Processor for NoOpProcessor {
        type I = I32Input;
        fn process(&self, input: &Input<Self::I>) -> UnifiedOutput {
            UnifiedOutput(input.0 .0)
        }
    }

    pub struct MultiplierProcessor(pub i32);

    impl Processor for MultiplierProcessor {
        type I = I32Input;
        fn process(&self, input: &Input<Self::I>) -> UnifiedOutput {
            UnifiedOutput(input.0 .0 * self.0)
        }
    }

    pub struct StringProcessor;

    impl Processor for StringProcessor {
        type I = String;
        fn process(&self, input: &Input<Self::I>) -> UnifiedOutput {
            UnifiedOutput(input.0.parse().unwrap())
        }
    }
}

mod output {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct UnifiedOutput(pub i32);
}

pub fn main() {
    let input_store = InputStore::default()
        .insert("input_a", 123)
        .insert("input_b", 567)
        .insert("input_c", "789");

    let processors = {
        let mut labelled_processors = Vec::new();
        // let mut labelled_processors: Vec<LabelledProcessor<Input<>>> = Vec::new(); // What's the correct type?
        labelled_processors.push(LabelledProcessor("input_a", Box::new(NoOpProcessor)));
        labelled_processors.push(LabelledProcessor(
            "input_b",
            Box::new(MultiplierProcessor(3)),
        ));
        // labelled_processors.push(LabelledProcessor("input_c", Box::new(StringProcessor)));

        labelled_processors
    };

    for processor in processors {
        let output = retrieve_input_and_process(&input_store, processor);
        println!("{:?}", output);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct I32Input(pub i32);

impl From<&String> for I32Input {
    fn from(s: &String) -> Self {
        Self(s.parse().unwrap())
    }
}

struct LabelledProcessor<I>(&'static str, Box<dyn Processor<I = I>>)
where
    for<'a> &'a String: Into<I>;

fn retrieve_input_and_process<T>(
    store: &InputStore,
    processor: LabelledProcessor<T>,
) -> UnifiedOutput
where
    for<'a> &'a String: Into<T>,
{
    let input = store.get(processor.0).unwrap();
    processor.1.process(&input)
}
```

When `// labelled_processors.push(LabelledProcessor("input_c", Box::new(StringProcessor)));` is uncommented, I get the below compilation error:

```bash
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<attempt2::processor::StringProcessor as attempt2::processor::Processor>::I == attempt2::I32Input`
   --> src/attempt2.rs:101:63
    |
101 |         labelled_processors.push(LabelledProcessor("input_c", Box::new(StringProcessor)));
    |                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type mismatch resolving `<attempt2::processor::StringProcessor as attempt2::processor::Processor>::I == attempt2::I32Input`
    |
note: expected this to be `attempt2::I32Input`
   --> src/attempt2.rs:75:18
    |
75  |         type I = String;
    |                  ^^^^^^
    = note: required for the cast from `attempt2::processor::StringProcessor` to the object type `dyn attempt2::processor::Processor<I = attempt2::I32Input>`
```

I think I've learnt enough to "get" what the issue is - the `labelled_processors` vec expects all its items to have the same *type*. My problem is I'm unsure how to rectify this. I've tried to leverage dynamic dispatch more (for example changing LabelledProcessor to `struct LabelledProcessor(&'static str, Box<dyn Processor<dyn Input>>);`). However these changes spiral to their own issues with the type system too.

Other answers I've found online generally don't address this level of complexity with respect to the nested generics/traits - stopping at 1 level with the answer being `let vec_x: Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait>> ...`. This makes me wonder if there's an obvious answer that can be reached that I've just missed or if there's a whole different pattern I should be employing instead to achieve this goal?

I'm aware of potentially utilizing enums as wel, but that would mean all usecases would need to be captured within this module and it may not be able to define inputs/outputs/processors in external modules.

A bit lost at this point.

--- EDIT ---

Some extra points:

- This is just an example, so things like InputStore basically converting everything to String is just an implementation detail. It's mainly to symbolize the concept of "the type needs to comply with some trait to be accepted", I just chose String for simplicity.

Comment: Why do you expose the type of `LabelledProcessor` in the first place, if you store all your things as `String` in your `InputStore`? Why not have them all take a `String` as argument?

Comment: I've updated the original post now, but `InputStore` opting to convert everything to String is just an implementation detail. It's meant to indicate "to be able to store things, the types being stored and retrieved from InputStore need to adhere to this contract". For this example I have provided, that's being able to be converted to/from String. You could equally switch it with serde but I was trying to avoid dependencies for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to make `retrieve_input_and_process` a method of `LabelledProcessor`, and then hide the type behind a trait:

```rust
use std::convert::From;

use processor::NoOpProcessor;

use self::{
    input::InputStore,
    output::UnifiedOutput,
    processor::{MultiplierProcessor, Processor, StringProcessor},
};

mod input {
    use std::collections::HashMap;

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct Input<T>(pub T);

    #[derive(Default)]
    pub struct InputStore(HashMap<String, String>);

    impl InputStore {
        pub fn insert<K, V>(mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Self
        where
            K: ToString,
            V: ToString,
        {
            let key = key.to_string();
            let value = value.to_string();
            self.0.insert(key, value);

            self
        }

        pub fn get<K, V>(&self, key: K) -> Option<Input<V>>
        where
            K: ToString,
            for<'a> &'a str: Into<V>,
        {
            let key = key.to_string();
            self.0.get(&key).map(|value| Input(value.as_str().into()))
        }
    }
}

mod processor {
    use super::{input::Input, output::UnifiedOutput};

    use super::I32Input;

    pub struct NoOpProcessor;

    pub trait Processor {
        type I;
        fn process(&self, input: &Input<Self::I>) -> UnifiedOutput;
    }

    impl Processor for NoOpProcessor {
        type I = I32Input;
        fn process(&self, input: &Input<Self::I>) -> UnifiedOutput {
            UnifiedOutput(input.0 .0)
        }
    }

    pub struct MultiplierProcessor(pub i32);

    impl Processor for MultiplierProcessor {
        type I = I32Input;
        fn process(&self, input: &Input<Self::I>) -> UnifiedOutput {
            UnifiedOutput(input.0 .0 * self.0)
        }
    }

    pub struct StringProcessor;

    impl Processor for StringProcessor {
        type I = String;
        fn process(&self, input: &Input<Self::I>) -> UnifiedOutput {
            UnifiedOutput(input.0.parse().unwrap())
        }
    }
}

mod output {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct UnifiedOutput(pub i32);
}

pub fn main() {
    let input_store = InputStore::default()
        .insert("input_a", 123)
        .insert("input_b", 567)
        .insert("input_c", "789");

    let processors = {
        let mut labelled_processors: Vec<Box<dyn LabelledProcessorRef>> = Vec::new();

        labelled_processors.push(Box::new(LabelledProcessor(
            "input_a",
            Box::new(NoOpProcessor),
        )));
        labelled_processors.push(Box::new(LabelledProcessor(
            "input_b",
            Box::new(MultiplierProcessor(3)),
        )));
        labelled_processors.push(Box::new(LabelledProcessor(
            "input_c",
            Box::new(StringProcessor),
        )));

        labelled_processors
    };

    for processor in processors {
        let output = processor.retrieve_input_and_process(&input_store);
        println!("{:?}", output);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct I32Input(pub i32);

impl From<&str> for I32Input {
    fn from(s: &str) -> Self {
        Self(s.parse().unwrap())
    }
}

struct LabelledProcessor<I>(&'static str, Box<dyn Processor<I = I>>);

impl<I> LabelledProcessorRef for LabelledProcessor<I>
where
    for<'a> &'a str: Into<I>,
{
    fn retrieve_input_and_process(&self, store: &InputStore) -> UnifiedOutput {
        let input = store.get(self.0).unwrap();
        self.1.process(&input)
    }
}

trait LabelledProcessorRef {
    fn retrieve_input_and_process(&self, store: &InputStore) -> UnifiedOutput;
}
```

```
UnifiedOutput(123)
UnifiedOutput(1701)
UnifiedOutput(789)
```

Comment: Awesome suggested approach. Seems so obvious now. I did consider making `retrieve_input_and_process` part of `LabelledProcessor`'s impl but never considered making it part of a separate trait. Seemed a bit redundant if it was only going to be implemented for one type but in reality the generic means there are several distinct types that need to be used the same way, so the trait makes sense. 

You mentioned this was one possible solution - what others did you think of?

Comment: Another solution would be to do a similar thing to the processors, where instead of giving them a value you give them the store object (maybe abstracted through a trait) and the processors themselves request an object of the correct type from the store. Then the `LabelledProcessor` itself could be without generic.

Comment: I see. What would that `InputStore` trait look like? Would it need to include details of the from/to string impl?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean with that :) I would abstract the `InputStore` behind a trait, and then give that trait to the processors. There's no reason to expose the inner working of the `InputStore` to the processors, that's what traits are for :)